# Can not use numeric expression in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I just stucked, is something wrong with P.NetPrice * 100 in SQL, I have tried it in MSQL SMS and it worked for me, how can I do that in Access.

Actually I wanted to do : ((P.NetPrice * 100) / I.Quantity)

[image]

Any help would be nice :)

Thanks

**Update**

---

```
SELECT R.Name, P.Name, I.Quantity, (P.NetPrice/100)*I.Quantity AS Price
FROM Receipt AS R INNER JOIN (Product AS P INNER JOIN Ingredients AS I ON P.ID = I.ProductID) ON R.ID = I.ReceiptID
WHERE (((R.ID)=Forms![frmReceipt]![cmbReceipt]));
```

works in query mode after entering parameter of the **cmbReceipt**

but not working in form view the same query asking for parameter **NetPrice**

[image]

Any tips ?

**Update**

---

Just forgot to call last column as **Net**Price after I've added a numeric expression, that was the reason access kept asking for parameter.

```
SELECT R.Name, P.Name, I.Quantity, (P.NetPrice/100)*I.Quantity AS NetPrice
FROM Receipt AS R INNER JOIN (Product AS P INNER JOIN Ingredients AS I ON P.ID = I.ProductID) ON R.ID = I.ReceiptID
WHERE (((R.ID)=Forms![frmReceipt]![cmbReceipt]));
```

**SOLVED NOW**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather the parameter causing the trouble. Specify it:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![frmReceipt]![cmbReceipt] Long;
SELECT R.Name, …
```

**Edit:**

Also, you must select *all* the fields you wish use:

```
SELECT R.Name, P.Name, I.Quantity, P.NetPrice, (P.NetPrice/100)*I.Quantity AS Price
```

Comment: Did it but did not helped. Access  automatically asks for parameter in popup after running Query, after entering the right parameter value the error comes.

Comment: And if you remove the parameter? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: Now I figured out the basic problem, you were right there was problem with parameter from form. It is gone now if I am running the Query in SQL query mode in access. The other problem is that I am using this Query after changing value in combobox. In form the query asks a parameter value of NetPrice. I am just confused, the same query works in query mode, but not in form mode.

Comment: If you call the query from code, it will not read the parameter, even if the form is open. If you open the query as "stand-alone" and the form is open, it will read the parameter.

Comment: Oh, I see now. It was because the query did not have the parameter NetPrice, after I've added numeric expression I forgot to call that as NetPrice, used only Price. Now it is clear and working. Anyway thanks to get me there :)

Comment: You are welcome! If all is nice and dandy, please mark as answered.